# After facebook login how to get User Information using javascript SDK in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, javascript, facebook, sdk

I have to implement **facebook login and also want to get logged in user's information** like birthday, firstname, Email address.

I have already done some other stuff like recent activities etc of facebook using **javascript SDK of facebook**.

i am developing **application in ASP.Net (C#).**

How can i get user information, Please provide me any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user's logged in and you asked for extended permissions (you can use Javascript to do that) you get an access token and then you can call the Facebook graph API. This is server side.

FB do not offer a C# SDK for their API so you will have to find one (or make you own)

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api